# JavaScript Object - Remap Properties (by Key)

Tags: javascript

Can you think of a better way to **remap** this JavaScript object:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "child.id": 456,
    "child.child.id": 789
}
```

... into this JavaScript object:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "child": {
        "id": 456,
        "child": {
            "id": 789
        }
    }
}
```

There must be a shorter or faster solution. This is my attempt:

```
var original = {
    "id": 123,
    "child.id": 456,
    "child.child.id": 789
};

var result = {};

Object.keys(original).forEach(function(key) {
    var node = result;
    var keys = key.match(/(\w+)/g);

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (!node[keys[i]]) {
            node[keys[i]] = {};
        }
        if (i == keys.length - 1) {
            node[keys[i]] = original[key];
        } else {
            node = node[keys[i]];
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went with your original approach, but used recursion and it seems to be slightly faster in the broswers I've tested (except for safari and opera and they are *exactly* equal, not sure why that is..):

```
function remapObject(original){
    var result = {};
    Object.keys(original).forEach(function(key) {
        function splitNode(node, nodes){
            var name = nodes.shift()
            node[name] = (nodes.length >= 1)
                ? splitNode(node[name] || {}, nodes)
                : original[key];
            return node;
        }
        splitNode(result, key.split("."));
    });
    return result;
}

var original = {
        "id": 123,
        "child.id": 456,
        "child.other": 789
    },
    result = remapObject(original)

console.log(original);
console.log(result);
```

fiddle is here:  http://jsfiddle.net/hyperthalamus/3A9NQ/
jsperf test is here: http://jsperf.com/mapping-by-keys

EDIT:
I had to do something very similar to this recently (again) after spending a lot of time working with closures and optimization, etc.  Below is a version that doesn't rely on Object.keys or array.forEach.  array.forEach is generally not good for performance and both of these methods [have limited browser support](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/).  The function below has been optimized for reuse as this function is used quite a bit in my app's initialization.  I am posting this here (3 months later) because it suited my needs particularly well and I thought I'd share even though this is probably overkill.

```
var remapObject = (function () {
    "use strict";
    var nodeSplit = function (key, original) {
        return function splitNode(node, nodes) {
            var name = nodes.shift();
            node[name] = (nodes.length >= 1) ? splitNode(node[name] || {}, nodes) : original[key];
            return node;
        };
    };
    return function (original) {
        var result = {},
            prop,
            splitNode;
        for (prop in original) {
            if (original.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                nodeSplit(prop, original)(result, prop.split("."));
            }
        }
        return result;
    };
}());
```

The function at the top is created once inside the initialization enclosure and returns functions to avoid creating a function inside a for loop as this is generally frowned on for optimization or so I'm told.

If the concern is file size, an compressed version is here:

```
var remapObject=function(){var h=function(a,b){return function g(d,e){var f=e.shift();d[f]=1<=e.length?g(d[f]||{},e):b[a];return d}};return function(a){var b={},c;for(c in a)a.hasOwnProperty(c)&&h(c,a)(b,c.split("."));return b}}();
```

Comment: Almost there @Shane: won't work with: `var original = {"id": 123, "child.id": 456, "child.other": 789};` for example. Like the **recursion** approach!

Comment: Try it now, if that works, I'll modify my original answer

http://jsfiddle.net/hyperthalamus/3A9NQ/2/

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! _(I'll update the question too.)_